# C# XML Get to Attribute and output an element

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, element

I've got this piece of XML, and I just need the value of an specific key. Like the sting input is "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b" and it just needs to read: "Lorem Ispum".

```
<data>
  <key id="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b" alt-id="1">
    <value>Lorem Ispum</value>
  </key>
  <key id="c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c" alt-id="2">
    <value>Dolor Sit Amet</value>
  </key>
</data>
```

Comment: OK, you need something, but what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
XDocument xdc = XDocument.Load("YourXMLFile");
var SomeValue = xdc.Descendants("key")
                   .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b")
                   .Descendants("value")
                   .FirstOrDefault()
                   .Value;
```

Comment: Thanks! That just did the trick!!